# INSERT from a SELECT making a column pair unique

Tags: php, mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table (simplified for example here):

```
CREATE TABLE msg
(
    msg_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    message TEXT,

    UNIQUE INDEX msg_index (msg_id, user_id);
);
```

I allow the user to add new messages with a simple INSERT INTO as in:

```
INSERT INTO msg (msg_id, user_id, message)
       VALUES ($_POST["id"], $user["id"], $_POST["message"]);
```

Once a message exists, I allow the user to create a *Duplicate*. The statement is pretty simple, I can do this:

```
INSERT INTO msg (msg_id, user_id, message)
       SELECT CONCAT(msg_id, "_Copy") AS msg_id, user_id, message
          WHERE msg_id = $_POST["id"];
```

That works fine the first time, only if a user try the *Duplicate* command again on the same message, then it fails because of the `UNIQUE INDEX` constrain.

Is there a way to change the `CONTACT()` statement to generate a unique identifier (i.e. "_Copy1", "_Copy2", ...) or do I have to test whether the `INSERT` succeeds and if not, try again with the next possible entry? (I know how to do that, I'm just wondering whether MySQL offers incredible features like making a set of columns unique automatically, like magic!)

Comment: Yes there is an awesome feature named AUTO_INCREMENT. Also don't forget to escape your user input.

Comment: @RolandStarke, Indeed, my implementation knows the `$_POST` may be tinted (i.e. an empty _message_ is not valid). Also I use `mysqli` which takes care of problems like special characters, etc. as I'm using a `bind()`. But for the example here, I did not see the point in making it too comlicated.

Comment: Yea I understand. Should have seen it from your score.... (I just took a short look at your profile and saw c++, c and assembly, so I thought you maybe write your first lines in php :D.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `RAND()` function in order to create random number (and you can search SO regarding how to generate random strings in MySQL), but I really don't think it's a good solution.

Your ID should be unique, and probably auto-incremented.
It would be much better to add a new column, maybe "source_msg" that will save the id of the original message (this way you can always know which is the original message the user duplicated the current message from).

In case its "original" message - just put there 0.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE msg
(
    msg_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    source_msg INT NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    message TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX msg_index (msg_id, user_id);
);
```

New Message:

```
INSERT INTO msg (msg_id, source_msg, user_id, message)
    VALUES (NULL, 0, $user["id"], $_POST["message"]);
```

Duplicate Message:

```
INSERT INTO msg (msg_id, source_msg, user_id, message)
    SELECT null, msg_id, user_id, message;
```

> Regardless - read about boby tables.

Comment: In my situation I need `msg_id` to be a string and be unique on a per user basis. Adding another column would make the `INSERT` statement work, but not the uniqueness of `msg_id` (i.e. I need the user to be able to reference a message by its identifier.)

Comment: I really advise you against this. Can you explain the reason for this requirement?

Comment: Users will be using that identifiers in other places than my system. I really don't see what's wrong with that...

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it is exposed to race conditions.  So, it might work almost all the time -- but not under heavy loads:

```
INSERT INTO msg (msg_id, user_id, message)
    SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN v_msg_id
                 ELSE CONCAT_WS('_', SUBSTRING_INDEX(v_msg_id, '_', 1), COUNT(*) + 1) AS msg_id,
           v_user_id, v_message
    FROM msg
    WHERE msg_id = v_msg_id;
```

Note:  This assumes that `msg_id` does not have an underscore.  It is easy to adjust the logic if that is a possibility.

A safer alternative would be appending a UUID to the end.  However, that is pretty ugly.

Comment: In my case, this only happens if a specific user clicks Duplicate and it is not likely that they will click it more than once at a time, so there should be no race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Since "msg_id" is a string, I would probably try to play with timestamps in milliseconds, so you are getting out of a box timestamps, performance (no need to search for all previous copies) and "more or less" uniqueness, which will be violated if you exceed a rate 1000 message copies per 1 second.

```
INSERT INTO msg (msg_id, user_id, message)
       SELECT CONCAT(msg_id, '_', ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000)) AS msg_id,
              user_id,
              message
       WHERE msg_id = $_POST['id'];
```

**Note**

This syntax `msg_id = $_POST['id'];` is really vulnerable because of potential SQL injections. I would recommend to use place holders and don't pass input directly in a query.

Comment: I'd rather have a number that makes sense. Like when you copy a file in your file system using your mouse (opposed to the way I generally do it: in my console.) The new file is often going to have a name such as `Copy of <blah>` and if that filename is already used: `Copy of <blah> (1)`, etc. Using the date would end up being a really large number that my users could not write easily. That ID is edited by the user too and reused in URLs... so that's in part why I wanted to avoid a SERIAL number too.